# I need help, percentages, ratios, proportions.

Tags: percentages

A community center is going on a trip to Philadelphia via several buses. The ratio of men to women to children is 1:2:3. If there are 150 people going on the trip, how many men are going? How many women are going? How many children are going?

Can somebody please help me figure this out? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be the number of men.  Then $x + 2x + 3x = 150$.  Can you do the rest?